# $\frac{d}{dt}(d\psi^t)_x(Z)=(d\psi^t)_x([X_H,Z])$ for a critical point $x$ of a Hamiltonian $H$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry, hamilton-equations

Let $W$ be a closed symplectic manifold, $H:W\to \Bbb R$ a Hamiltonian, $x\in W$ a critical point of $H$, $X_H$ the associated Hamiltonian vector field, and $\psi^t:W\to W$ the (global) flow of $X_H$. Since $x$ is a critical point we have $\psi^t(x)=x$ for all $t$. Suppose that $x$ is nondegenerate as a periodic solution of the Hamiltonian system. This means that the differential $(d\psi^1)_x:T_xW\to T_xW$ does not 1 as an eigenvalue. In particular $(d\psi^1)_x(Z)\neq Z$ for every nonzero $Z\in T_xW$.

I am reading Proposition 5.4.5 of Audin, Damian's book *Morse Theory and Floer Homology*, and it is written as follows: Since $\psi^0=\text{id}$, there must be a $t$ such that $$\frac{d}{dt}(d\psi^t)_x(Z)\neq0,$$
and this derivative equals $(d\psi^t)_x([X_H,Z]).$

1. Why does there exist such $t$? I can see that the map $t\mapsto (d\psi^t)_x(Z)$ is nonconstant, so its derivative cannot be identically zero. But why do we need "Since $\psi^0=\text{id}$"?
2. Why does the derivative equals $(d\psi^t)_x([X_H,Z])$?

Any hints will be appreciated

Comment: I think for (1) the idea is that the map could be some non-identity constant. Having $\psi^0 = \text{id}$ rules this out. For (2), time derivatives in the Hamiltonian setting are just $\mathcal{L}_{X_H}$. You might need an application of Cartan's identity and/or the coordinate free definition of the exterior derivative to finish the argument.